# Нужна помощь с popup окнами

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, popup

Здравствуйте участники форума, скажу честно js только начинаю изучать. Нужна ваша помощь небольшая знаю что решение простое но сам дойти не могу в общем вот скрипт попап окна

сам скрипт

```
<script>
// Получаем попап
var popup = document.getElementById('mypopup');

// Получаем кнопку, открывающую попап
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Получаем span, закрывающий попап
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// Открываем попап по клику
btn.onclick = function() {
    popup.style.display = "block";
}

// Закрываем по кнопке
span.onclick = function() {
    popup.style.display = "none";
}

// Закрываем попап по клику в любом месте
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == popup) {
        popup.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

стили и сам html

```
<style>
/* Стиль модального окна Mobirise */
.popup {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Контент модального окна Mobirise */
.popup-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Включаем анимацию */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* Кнопка закрыть */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.popup-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.popup-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.popup-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}
</style>

<!-- Код попап окна Mobirise-->
<div id="mypopup" class="popup">
  <!-- Контент попап окна Mobirise -->
  <div class="popup-content">
    <div class="popup-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>popup Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="popup-body">
      <p>Some text in the popup Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="popup-footer">
      <h3>popup Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

и кнопка вызова

```
<button id="myBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Открыть попап</button>
```

Хотел добавить эту кнопку несколько раз, то есть, есть четыре товара по порядку, и под каждым есть кнопка заказа, и при нажатии по любой из этих четырёх кнопок, должен открываться один и тот же попап, но попап срабатывает только у самого первого товара остальные, просто нажимаются без какого либо эффекта. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, буду очень признателен помощи.

Comment: Атрибут id у элемента должен быть уникальным. Вызов document.getElementById("myBtn") возвращает вам только одну кнопку и только к этой кнопке добавляете обработчик собитий

Comment: Так и что сделать в этом случае подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: Пройтись циклом по всех кнопках и каждой добавить обработчик. Не забывайте -  id элемента должен быть уникальным.

Comment: тоесть четыре раза прописать весь скрипт? для каждой кнопки отдельно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убрать `id` у кнопки.
Убрать `// Получаем кнопку, открывающую попап ...`
Заменить `// Открываем попап по клику ...` на код:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.btn')).forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    popup.style.display = 'block';
  });
});
```

А потом хоть мильён кнопок можете добавлять. Главное, чтобы у них `class` был одинаковый.

Comment: ой спасибо то есть там где '.btn' надо прописать тот класс который объединяет все кнопки на которых попап будет так?

Comment: @ВалентинЛифанов Именно так.